# Cannot check if a field contains also number

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to check if a field in a specific table contains also number, in particular I have a record that have the field `name` which contains this value: `Besëlidhja Lezhë vs. Tërbuni Pukë 1 - 1`, so I'm trying to get also all the rows of that table that contains a number inside the field `name`. I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `venue` where `name` like '%[0-9]%'
```

but this will return an empty result, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should tell you if `name` contains any digit (not tested)

```
SELECT * FROM venue WHERE name REGEXP '[0-9]'
```

Comment: this worked but is possible add a specific pattern like search only when there are two number with a dash in the middle? Such as: 2 - 1?

Comment: @Charanoglu . . . This answers the question you asked (and is in my opinion the best answer).  You should accept this (or another answer).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM venue
WHERE name like '%0%' or name like '%1%' or name like '%2%' or name like '%3%'
```

and so on til you get to 9. I hope this helps

Comment: is possible add a specific pattern like search only when there are two number with a dash in the middle? Such as: 2 - 1?

Comment: I don't have a table set up like yours so I can't test, but perhaps you can try this query:

select * 
from venue
where name like '%[0-9]-[0-9]%'

Comment: this will return empty, you can easily test creating a dummy table with the record that I wrote in question

Comment: try with the like clause like so:
select * from venue where name like '%[0-9]%-%[0-9]%' 

its working on my test table

Comment: Also be sure to remove the ' ' from your attributes/table names. EX: 'venue'

Comment: when I execute this: `select * from venue where name like '%[0-9]%-%[0-9]%'` I got nothing

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a Regular Expression that filters for names in your name column with numeric characters  . For example:

SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE name REGEXP '[a-z]...[0-9]';

mySQL allows you to use regular expression as a filter !

This should select out for names like Tërbuni Pukë 1 - 1. If you want to practice regular expressions this is a great website to test whether you have the right regex. https://regex101.com/

Hope this helps !

Comment: is possible add a specific pattern like search only when there are two number with a dash in the middle? Such as: 2 - 1?